# Heroku Paperclip S3 demo not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-s3

I'm trying to get my first s3 app to work. Thought i'd go for an easy out of the box but cannot get the basic heroku demo (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/paperclip-s3) to work.

Absolutely back to basics

- demo app - no changes
- S3 bucket in US zone
- 3 env variables set in heroku

always gives "Something went wrong". no errors (despite debug log level)

```
    2016-02-12T05:06:09.151401+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/friends" host=blooming-dusk-48208.herokuapp.com request_id=6a2d3736-a0f7-4aea-97a4-b5b06f407500 fwd="101.109.255.204" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=187ms status=500 bytes=919
```

heroku config

```
    === blooming-dusk-48208 Config Vars
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID:     A*******
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: y*******************
    AWS_BUCKET_NAME:       us-buckettest1
    SECRET_KEY_BASE:       7a4*******************************
```

various things out there to try/have changed

- aws-sdk <2.0
- add region and endpoing variables (have tried the sugggested EU domains and just US domains)
- env name changes (these seem illogical to me)
- could get local version (using fakes3, see separate issue but seems to be unrelated and more about local ports etc.)

has anyone got this to work as suggested in the article?

any pointers really appreciated, thanks

Ben

UPDATE1

*log after git push*

```
    2016-02-12T09:31:36.694199+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
    2016-02-12T09:31:36.694204+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 4.1.2 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:42106
    2016-02-12T09:31:36.694206+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
    2016-02-12T09:31:36.694207+00:00 app[web.1]: => Notice: server is listening on all interfaces (0.0.0.0). Consider using 127.0.0.1 (--binding option)
    2016-02-12T09:31:36.694207+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
    2016-02-12T09:31:36.976431+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/friends" host=blooming-dusk-48208.herokuapp.com request_id=287c48c6-9b29-46eb-8bd1-35462c0732c5 fwd="101.109.255.204" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=306ms status=500 bytes=919
```

Comment: can you please show the logs using `heroku logs` command

Answer (score 0):

I decided to start from scratch again and it works. I feel so sheepish. I'm not sure what I did, I recall adding new  /different variables variables but surely having additional config variables (but not referencing them within the app code should not cause issues)?